# Composition of Stereographic Projection, Reflection and Inverse of Stereographic Projection

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $s$ be the stereographic projection from the sphere without a northpole to the complex plane and let $r$ be the reflection  $(x, y, z) \to (x, −y, −z)$. I am trying to figure out where the composition $ s \circ r \circ s^{-1}$ is defined.

A theoretical attempt:
I know that s is onto, the function goes to every point on complex plane. Then $s^{-1}$ is defined everywhere, it is not onto (since there's no point that goes to (0,0,1) but it is one to one. $r$ just totates the sphere so that the hole is on the south pole now. $s$ maps the sphere to complex plane.

I don't really know what I need to do now. My intuition tells me to find a way to describe which (x,y) from complex goes to sphere with a formula as a start I guess. Then what? I don't want you to write the proof for me but I can't understand what to show and write here. My intuition tells me that it is defined everywhere $s^{-1}$ is defined everywhere and r is defined everywhere. But in  the last part, now we have a sphere which has 2 holes on both poles. Did I do anything right or am I heading to the right way? What should I do next? Thanks a lot in advance!